# Why am I getting ' setAdListener must be called on the main UI thread' when I am running it on the UI thread

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add interstitial ads to my game. It is built on a framework from a book. The constructor is:

```
 public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
        world = new World();
        clueLetters = new String[10];
        levelNo = SettingsObject.levelUnlock;
        getWord();
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(AndroidGame.context);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1861496496821617/");

        //Create an ad request
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

        AndroidGame.activityReference.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()

            {
                // Set AdListener
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        super.onAdClosed();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Looper.prepare();
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

    }
```

However, I get the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: setAdListener must be called on the main UI thread.
```

Can you tell me why I am getting that error and how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the a similar/same framework. The best way is to set up the interstitial ads in the AndroidGame activity class and use an interface to show the ads in your game screen:

**First create the interface class:**

```
public interface MyActivityListener {
    public void showInterstitial();
}
```

**Then in your AndroidGame class, implement the interface:**

```
public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game, MyActivityListener {
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(AndroidGame.context);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1861496496821617/");
        //Create an ad request
        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

                // Set AdListener
                interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        super.onAdClosed();
                    }
                });
        }

@Override
    public void showInterstitial() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {   
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded())
                   interstitialAd.show();       
            }
        });

    }
}
```

With this, any time you want to show ads in any `screen`, you just get call the `showInterstitial()` method. **Example in your game screen:**

```
public class GameScreen extends Screen{
    MYActivityListener mL;
public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
        mL = (MyActivityListener)game;
        world = new World();
        clueLetters = new String[10];
        levelNo = SettingsObject.levelUnlock;
        getWord();
        mL.showInterstitial();
    }

}
```

I use this implementation to do all work that requires running on the UI thread (hide and show banner ads, rate/share app, storing scores etc. Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. It works. However, I still would like to know why I got the error I did get.

Comment: This is pretty old, but I just happend to be in the same situation. As it turns out, I had to move the new AdRequest.Builder(); inside the Runnable to order to resolve it.